# How are cameras utilized in SmartThings?

Tags: samsung-smartthings, digital-cameras, mobile-applications

I'm considering getting an outdoor camera like [Ring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DM6BDA4). Cameras like Ring are listed in the recommended compatible devices in the SmartThings market. So, I'm curious what sort of automation events are available with cameras like this?

- Motion Detection?
- Presence?
- Can you control notifications of camera system with other SmartThings events?

Comment: what you are asking should be indicated in the documentation

Comment: https://support.ring.com/hc/en-us/articles/204366534-Motion-Detection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get what you mean by presence, but you can get notifications of door bell button push and / or when motion detection gets triggered.

I understood from the specifications that with SmartThings you can switch either one of them on or off and also drive another SmartThings device like a light switch based on the notification.

There's more information available in the [SmartThings Documentation](https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-us/articles/214288206-Ring-Doorbell) on the Ring Doorbell.

Comment: I don't know if Ring (or other cameras) incorporate facial recognition to set presence of specific people. Much like you can use your cell phone as a presence sensor (using GPS), the cameras could potentially use facial recognition to detect presence. Thank you for the link to the documentation, that's what I was looking for.